# how to do something when property created with pure js

Tags: javascript

I want to do something when new property added to Object named `Session`.
for example, i create new property :

```
Session["name"] = 'Yoza';
```

when `Session.name` created, i need to do something.

how to do that?

Comment: Do something as in automatically doing something? There's the observer pattern for that.

Comment: If you know the property names to monitor in advance, you can create `setters` and `getters` for them which will trigger your code when they are assigned or retrieved.

Comment: yes automatically do something or call function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a setter function. Something like

```
Session.set = function(property, value){
    Session[property]=value;
    someCallback();
}
```

Comment: thanks may be this is not what i ask, but this solve my problem